# iOS new mail does not appear in inbox

Tags: ios, email, imap, apns

I am using iOS mail with an IMAP push enabled inbox.

Notifications for new emails appear instantly but sometimes the new email does not appear in the inbox (it seems that it needs to be downloaded first, taking up to 2-3 seconds).

Is there a way to eliminate this time and always have the mail in the inbox without waiting for it to appear?

This happens on multiple different accounts.
Is this intended behavior and can it be tweaked?

Comment: I don't think that ios mail understands pushes and just relies on polling

Comment: @mmmmmm but it gets new mails as push notifications (outside of any poll intervals).... I think there is a problem with gmail... but thats probably a different story.

Comment: https://www.igeeksblog.com/gmail-push-notifications-not-working-iphone-ipad/

Comment: @mmmmmm thanks I know about the problems with gmail already. The problem above can be seen on other email providers

Comment: The article does say that Apple does not allow push mail

Comment: @mmmmmm yes in regards to gmail but I am facing the issue on various other accouts, none of them is gmail, but thanks anyway